# Error while making calculator on Ruby?

Tags: ruby, calculator

While trying to make a calculator in Ruby, using TextWrangler's #! function (Compiled in Terminal) I encountered an error. When I add 2+2 the answer it returns is 2.0. I tried other functions, for example calculating a specific percentage of a certain number, no matter what I tried doing the answer was always 0.0. I checked the syntax, using the #! function, and there were no errors. I know I made it unnecessarily wrong, but it is easier to read it this way for me.

```
loop do
print 
equation = gets.chomp

if equation.include?"^"
    exponent_e = equation.split("^")
    result_e = equation[0].to_f ** equation[1].to_f
    puts "#{equation} = #{result_e}"
elsif equation.include?"%"
    percent_e = equation.split("%")
    number = equation[0].to_f / 100
    result_p = number * equation[1].to_f
    puts "#{equation} = #{result_p}"
elsif equation.include?"/"
    equation.split("/")
    result_d = equation[0].to_f / equation[1].to_f
    puts "#{equation} = #{result_d}"
elsif equation.include?"*"
    equation.split("*")
    result_m = equation[0].to_f * equation[1].to_f
    puts "#{equation} = #{result_m}"
elsif equation.include?"+"
    equation.split("+")
    result_a = equation[0].to_f + equation[1].to_f
    puts "#{equation} = #{result_a}"
elsif equation.include?"-"
    equation.split("-")
    result_s = eqaution[0].to_f - equation[1].to_f
    puts "#{equation} = #{result_s}"
end
end
```

Comment: FWIW, `loop` is uncommon in ruby, and `case` statements can be used in place of long `if/elsif/end` statements.

Comment: Please use proper indentation for your code. Your future team members will thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not storing the split in a variable. You need to do something like this:

```
elsif equation.include?"+"
    res = equation.split("+")
    result_a = res[0].to_f + res[1].to_f
```